# How to sort the returned accumulator by the property value in alphabetical order? - Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to write a javascript function to show multiple drop down. As you can see this. State.data contains the entire api data. Here this.state.data is an array of object.

I want to sort the returned accumulator by the property value. Value and label is same basically

```
  getOptions(propertyName) {
return this.state.data.reduce((accum, elem, i) => {
  const accumulator = [...accum];
  if(!accumulator.some((e) => { return e.value === elem[propertyName]; })) {
    if(elem[propertyName] !== '' && elem[propertyName] !== '-') {
      accumulator.push({
        id: i,
        value: elem[propertyName],
        label: elem[propertyName]
      });
    }
  }
  return accumulator;
}, []);
 }
```

I only want to do using plain JS. I can use lodash but I cannot use Jquery. I am more interested to use plain Vanilla JS

Comment: maybe you add some data to sort and which problem you have to do so.

Comment: I want to sort all fields of my api data variable before the 3rd line? Can you please make this more clear with a small example.

Comment: @NinaScholz my bad i have changed the thought approach. I want to sort the returned accumulator by value. Value and label is same basically.

Comment: @HarshitJuneja have changed the thought approach. I want to sort the returned accumulator by value. Value and label is same basically

Comment: can u share a small `dataset` example- Provide a dummy input and expected output

Comment: Your value and label look the same to me, both equal to the property name.

accumulator.push({
        id: i,
        value: elem[propertyName],
        label: elem[propertyName]
      });

Comment: What field do you want to sort the array on, value or label?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a comparator function to compare using a specific property:

```
data.sort(function (a,b) {
    return a.propertyName > b.propertyName ? 1 : b.propertyName > a.propertyName ? -1 : 0;
})
```

And in general if you want to sort an array of strings (not objects) alphabetically just call `sort()` on data. The call `reverse()` if you want it in descending order.

Comment: have changed the thought approach. I want to sort the returned accumulator by value. Value and label is same basically